# How insert tikz picture in to beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have that picture

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-4.3,-11.98) rectangle (33.88,6.3);
\draw (-0.48,-3.42) node[anchor=north west] {Official};
\draw (2.48,-0.54) node[anchor=north west] {Citizen};
\draw (0.62,-3.06)--node[above,sloped] {$b>0$}node[below,sloped] {bride} (2.8349953328119706,-1.0366869556044498);
\draw (0.6,-3.9)--  node[above,sloped] {$b=0$}node[below,sloped] {nobride}(2.753375039560603,-5.988773788373784);
\draw (3.5,-0.28)-- node[above,sloped] {pay}node[below,sloped] {end report} (5.708982562266176,1.7498758680283781);
\draw (4.14,-0.87)-- node[above,sloped] {pay}node[below,sloped] {silenty}(7.14,-0.87);
\draw (3.36,-1.06)--node[above,sloped] {refuse}node[below,sloped] {silently}  (5.502014662422205,-3.1604221447052696);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-4.3,-11.98) rectangle (33.88,6.3);
\draw (-0.48,-3.42) node[anchor=north west] {Official};
\draw (2.48,-0.54) node[anchor=north west] {Citizen};
\draw (0.62,-3.06)--node[above,sloped] {$b>0$}node[below,sloped] {bride} (2.8349953328119706,-1.0366869556044498);
\draw (0.6,-3.9)--  node[above,sloped] {$b=0$}node[below,sloped] {nobride}(2.753375039560603,-5.988773788373784);
\draw (3.5,-0.28)-- node[above,sloped] [red]{\textbf{pay}}node[below,sloped] [red]{\textbf{end report}} (5.708982562266176,1.7498758680283781);
\draw (4.14,-0.87)-- node[above,sloped] {pay}node[below,sloped] {silenty}(7.14,-0.87);
\draw (3.36,-1.06)--node[above,sloped] {refuse}node[below,sloped] {silently}  (5.502014662422205,-3.1604221447052696);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-4.3,-11.98) rectangle (33.88,6.3);
\draw (-0.48,-3.42) node[anchor=north west] {Official};
\draw (2.48,-0.54) node[anchor=north west] {Citizen};
\draw (0.62,-3.06)--node[above,sloped] {$b>0$}node[below,sloped] {bride} (2.8349953328119706,-1.0366869556044498);
\draw (0.6,-3.9)--  node[above,sloped] [red]{$\textbf{b=0}$}node[below,sloped] [red]{\textbf{nobride}}(2.753375039560603,-5.988773788373784);
\draw (3.5,-0.28)-- node[above,sloped] [red]{\textbf{pay}}node[below,sloped] [red]{\textbf{end report}} (5.708982562266176,1.7498758680283781);
\draw (4.14,-0.87)-- node[above,sloped] {pay}node[below,sloped] {silenty}(7.14,-0.87);
\draw (3.36,-1.06)--node[above,sloped] {refuse}node[below,sloped] {silently}  (5.502014662422205,-3.1604221447052696);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I need to insert it in one frame, but nothing happend. Of course beamer is set on document

Comment: Your MWE is not a beamer document. Please, paste one example which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to change the color for each slide with a newcommand:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

 \newcommand*\nodeonecolor{}
 \newcommand*\nodetwocolor{}
 \only<2->{\renewcommand*\nodeonecolor{red}}
 \only<3->{\renewcommand*\nodetwocolor{red}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.9cm,y=0.7cm]
\clip(-4.3,-11.98) rectangle (33.88,6.3);
\draw (-0.48,-3.42) node[anchor=north west] {Official};
\draw (2.48,-0.54) node[anchor=north west] {Citizen};
\draw (0.62,-3.06)--node[above,sloped] {$b>0$}node[below,sloped] {bride} (2.8349953328119706,-1.0366869556044498);
\draw (0.6,-3.9)--  node[above,sloped] [\nodetwocolor]{$\textbf{b=0}$}node[below,sloped] [\nodetwocolor]{\textbf{nobride}}(2.753375039560603,-5.988773788373784);
\draw (3.5,-0.28)-- node[above,sloped] [\nodeonecolor]{\textbf{pay}}node[below,sloped] [\nodeonecolor]{\textbf{end report}} (5.708982562266176,1.7498758680283781);
\draw (4.14,-0.87)-- node[above,sloped] {pay}node[below,sloped] {silenty}(7.14,-0.87);
\draw (3.36,-1.06)--node[above,sloped] {refuse}node[below,sloped] {silently}  (5.502014662422205,-3.1604221447052696);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i see were was my mistake. I try insert all that text into one frame, without newcomands. Know i gate it. Thank again

Comment: Please accept my answer if it works for you. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.